# MYSQL database crashing frequently due to error in configuration

Tags: mysql, crash, linode

I have just shifted my website to Linode and I am currently on its 1 GB RAM Plan. By default, number of mysql users was set to 100. This lead to `Too many connections` error.

I edited the mysql settings again with the help of this . However, now the database is crashing almost every day !

Here are my current mysql settings are :-

```
key_buffer              = 100M
max_allowed_packet      = 1M
thread_stack            = 128K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 150
table_cache       ​ ​     = 1024​
query_cache_limit       = 300M
query_cache_size        = 300M ​
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
key_buffer              = 100M
```

Can anyone suggest me some changes or the reason why my databases are crashing so frequently ? I can also add more details about my server on demand.

**EDIT**

I have added mysql_close($con) everywhere, but that has further increased problems for my website somehow.Connections is increasing exponentially in the result shown below :-

```
mysql> show status like '%onn%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects         | 48    |
| Connections              | 1634  |
| Max_used_connections     | 8     |
| Ssl_client_connects      | 0     |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0     |
| Ssl_finished_connects    | 0     |
| Threads_connected        | 4     |
+--------------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Hi Prashant, do you have connections that aren't being closed properly? When I've encountered this in the past it was due to connections that were not being closed. Unless you are getting an insane amount of traffic on this box you shouldn't even reach the 100 user limit.

Comment: Are the connections not closed by default at the end of file execution ?

Comment: Hi Prashant, the connections have to be explicitly closed - what language are you using on your website that is querying the database?

Comment: I am currently using PHP as my server side language

Comment: Check this out here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Comment: Is there any way to find out number of open connections ?

Comment: Personally I use a 3rd party tool called Navicat - it has a nice interface that shows open connections - however this may be available in MySql Work Bench - although I have used used this lately

Comment: @Loren I have edited my question a bit. Please have a look

Comment: Hi, are you able to fix the issue? I am facing a similar problem. It is happening with my wordpress blog.

Comment: @Subhra Yes, Just switch to InnoDB. Check my answer for this question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not closing connections then obviously this would cause database to eventually crash. A restart will flush all connections that is why you server is probably restarting.

So fix your application and close connections. In the meanwhile you can have this script to kill the opened connections staying dead in your process-list. The script will kill everything that is stalled in the processlist for 500 sec. You may change the time as per need basis.

```
SECONDS_TOO_LONG=500
QUERIES_RUNNING_TOO_LONG=`/mysql/bin/mysql -u user -p'password' -ANe"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user<>'system user' AND time >= ${SECONDS_TOO_LONG}"`
if [ ${QUERIES_RUNNING_TOO_LONG} -gt 0 ]
then
    KILLPROC_SQLSTMT="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('KILL QUERY ',id,';') SEPARATOR ' ') KillQuery FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user<>'system user' AND time >= ${SECONDS_TOO_LONG}"
    /mysql/bin/mysql -u user -p'pass' -ANe"${KILLPROC_SQLSTMT}" | /mysql/bin/mysql -u user -p'pass'
fi;
```

Comment: You are probably using MYISAM, you may like to enable your query cache so that it is served from memory faster. these can be a good starting point.query_cache_limit = 350M
query_cache_size = 300M

Comment: if you share more information on your requirements, hardware, application and current database I would be able to advise you much further on how to use MYSQL more efficiently

Comment: umm could be but i have to write it then. BUt this is bash script and would perfectly fine on linux box. ANd could be executed by a cronjob every 2-5 mins...

Comment: thats what i said in my comment you are using MYISAM.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the main source of increasing exponential connections was my table itself. I was using MYISAM db. It actually locks the entire table before making any update. So, as a result if too many users come to my website, it was creating trouble.

Solution :-

I changed my database to InnoDB. It locks only individual rows which are required. This has limited to no of connections at a time to as low as single digit. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899479/converting-a-myisam-table-to-innodb-if-unique-keys-are-lengthy/) is another question which helped me in solving the issue completely.