# Converting a MYISAM table to INNODB if unique keys are lengthy

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

Since MYISAM locks the complete table every time, I am thinking of converting my MYISAM table to InnoDB. However, INNODB requires the unique and primary keys to be within 767 bytes.

So, I am getting this error :-

```
#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

My unique Keys are a bit lengthy. So, what is the best way for me to convert my table to INNODB ?

Here is the screenshot describing my table

[image]

Thanks

Comment: show table definition, please. What collation are you using?

Comment: @tombom My collation is utf8_unicode_ci . I am adding a screenshot of my table structure as an update to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the keys seen in the screenshot are all you've got, the key at issue here is `query_id`. As a 300-character UTF8 column, it ends up using 900 bytes alone.

You'll need to limit the index to a portion of that column — say, maybe the first 100 characters?

```
DROP INDEX query_id ON tablename
CREATE INDEX query_id ON tablename (query_id, position, prod(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Before converting the table, adjust its order so that the primary key column is in order

```
> ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY 'primary_key_column';
```

This will pre-arrange the table so that it can be converted quickly without a lot of re-arranging required in MySQL. Then, simply change the table engine:

```
> ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE = INNODB;
```